# find if collection not exists in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a case where i have `5 forms`. And user have to fill `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd` and `4th` form and every form has it's different `collection(table)`. And in `5th` form, I am displaying some fields from `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd` and `4th` form by calling **GET API**.

Actually, I am showing the list of `5` forms to user. User can click on any form from `first 4 forms` and then fill it. When user clicks on `5th` form then i am **calling an api to get first 4 forms fields**.

**Now my question is:** As i am calling api in 5th form to get data from first 4 forms. If a user fill only first form, and leave other forms and clicked on 5th form as only `1st` form collection exists but `2nd`, `3rd` and `4th` form collection is not exists. **So, How to handle this situtation?**

Answer (score 0):

can  your clearify more what you want to return if 2nd..4th form is empty ..

From my point of view, you are storing forms in array or object.

If you want check empty form in get api then implement checks like

if(arr[2]==" ")

or object sendond index is empty and so on for other form(index)

Or you want to implement in post API if any form is empty then keep in input field as required or check all form value while posting form.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that comes in my mind is First you should not allow the user to fill next forms if he does not fill the previous forms, you can track this by js click function and you can also add the all data in the same collection but if you want to place it in different collections still its ok.

**One thing that i want to ask** is how do you track that the same user filled the previous forms ? if you are tracking it by id then its easy

just when you make a api call check that if the data exist with this user name in the previous table collection then show the data else display a message to fill the previous forms first